# Generate database table dynamically

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, dynamic

I need to design a database which is going to hold huge data into it. I have to use RDBMS database(SQL Sever or MySQL have not decided yet). Following is the simplified and standard database design I can think of:

[image]

However, due to huge data that node and relationship table(millions to billions record and keep growing) required to hold, I am planning to dynamically generate node and relationship table for each tree. The dynamic design will be as follow :

[image]

So each time the new tree or version is cloned, new database tables will be created based on version id and tree id. And the name of dynamically generated table will be stored in `tree.node_table_name` and `tree.relationship_table_name`

**Example :**

If you create a new tree(id = 10) for version(id = 4), then the table names will be 4_10_node and 4_10_relationship and these names will be saved into tree table in `tree.node_table_name` and `tree.relationship_table_name` respectively.

**Questions:**

1. Is it a good idea to create tables dynamically?
2. What am I thinking is doable?
3. Is there any other way I can achieve what I am trying to do? (I am aware of partitioning but that is required to be done manually, I want to do it automatically)

**UPDATE :**

Each version can have more than 500 million nodes and I have many such version which will make overall node table row count to billions. Hence, the idea of creating a seperate table dynamically.

Comment: The answer to "should I make a bunch of identical tables" is almost always "no". If you're separating nodes into tables based on tree-version, it is mostly likely better to just have a single node table that includes the nodes' tree-version and index with that.

Comment: I understand I can do that and I have shown that in the first diagram. However, the node table rows get incremented each time the new version/tree is created and row count in a single table will be billions causing performance issues. That is why I am planning to create a table dynamically.

Comment: Would partitioning make sense?

Comment: If you're talking billions, you're talking one table with billions or thousands of tables with millions; the latter scenario is rarely useful... especially when indexing makes everything generally O(log N). _I would not be surprised if the overhead cost for constructing queries for such a multi-table design actually negates most (if any) benefit such a design might yield._

Comment: DO NOT fall down the rabbit hole of premature optimization. This is exactly what you are doing here. You are suggesting a non-standard design to deal with a performance problem that does not actually exist. This is one of the worst possible design decisions you can make. Stick with the tried and true architectures. Then **IF** a performance issue comes to light you deal with it then.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestion. I will look into the partition and follow the traditional and proven database design.

Comment: @Uueerdo do you think only indexing should be ok or I should do partition too?

Comment: I think worrying about portioning before you know you need it would be premature optimization as well. The benefit of partitioning greatly depends on knowing how you will be accessing the data; if you know you're only going to be querying one "tree" at a time, it might make sense to partition according to tree id (if you expect your trees to be roughly the same size), but unlike the table splitting you were considering partitioning does not affect the structure of your queries, so it is relatively easy to add later (even if the ALTER might take a while to reconstruct the table.)

Comment: ...but if you're querying frequently by `node.name` without any sort of qualifying tree identification, partitioning could even hurt performance.